# Is it possible to link a local testing docker-airflow environment to an existing Airflow on GCP?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I just have set up Airflow on local, encapsulated in a docker container.

I was wondering if it would be possible to link this Airflow local environment to an actual Airflow/Composer service on GCP?

Is there a way to do this with docker containers?

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "link"?

Comment: @hexacyanide i'm looking up for a solution to run/test GCP airflow DAGs directly in my local airflow environment, or maybe create a custom airflow connection to my local docker-airflow container

Comment: So to clarify, you wish to control Airflow locally using Cloud Composer?

Comment: @hexacyanide it's more like i wish i could test my Composer tasks but on the Airflow instance of my own machine

Comment: What's stopping you from copying the DAGs from Composer to your local Airflow environment?

Comment: @hexacyanide i was asked if this kind of configuration was possible to know the limits of the tool

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Composer runs its own instance of Airflow, so you can't set up a Composer environment that controls an instance of Airflow running on your own machine. However, if you run your own Kubernetes cluster and set up networking between your own machine(s) and the Composer environment's GKE cluster, then you can have Airflow tasks run in your on-prem cluster.

Comment: thanks for your help, i will take a look at the networking solution through kubernetes possibilities

Comment: is it possible to run workers on-prem without GKE cluster, create connection to meta store and redis in GCP?